# How to use auto increment field in insert for CI 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I try to insert data to a table in CI 3 that has fields as below:
[image]

pageid is auto increment and I write code in model as this:

```
 $data = array(
            'title'=>$title,
            'description'=>$des,
            'url'=>'page/view/'.pageid
        );
        $this->db->insert('page',$data);
```

The problem is that the pageid is unknown as the field name. What should I do because I want to concatenate pageid to url?

Comment: i dont understant what you want to do ? can u give an example ?

Comment: When I insert data to the table, I don't insert on auto-increment field "pageid" but I want to use that field in other field. For example, if write sql it seems like this: insert into page(title, description, url) values('About','some description', concat('page/view', pageid));

Comment: ok that means you want to use that generated id value in other field. for example if you insert one record the id of that record is 3 and you  wan to use this 3 in other field?

Comment: yes, I need to do that.

Comment: ok see my code may be it will help you....

Comment: is it helpful ? have you solved ?

Answer (score 1):

You need two query for it

1)You need to insert `title and description` first and get last page id from database

```
$data = array(
    'title' => $title,
    'description' => $des
);

$this->db->insert('page', $data);
$page_id = $this->db->insert_id();// get last pageid
```

2)Update `url` second

```
$data = array(
'url' => 'page/view/'.$page_id
);
$this->db->where('pageid'$page_id);// update with page id
$this->db->update('page', $data);
```

Comment: What you don't know??

Answer (score 1):

> OK so you can add all data first then after insert just update the url
>   field.

```
$data = array(
    'title' => $title,
    'description' => $des,
     'url'=>'page/view/'
);

$this->db->insert('page', $data);
$page_id = $this->db->insert_id();
```

> 2)Now update URL

```
$update= array(
'url' => 'page/view/'.$page_id
);
$this->db->where('page_id'$page_id);
$this->db->update('page', $update);
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

**Common & Easy Method**

Goto

1. Phpmyadmin
2. select your `database`, then go to `page` table.
3. Click `structure` on top.
4. Click `Change`, in front of `id` field.
5. Then there is check box with **AI(Auto Increment)**
6. ***Check that and click save***

---

**If with code(use this)**

```
public function FunctionName()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT id FROM pages ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    $id = $result['id']; // or some times $result[0]['id']

    $data = array(
            'title'         => $title,
            'description'   => $des,
            'url'           => 'page/view/'.pageid,
            'id'            => $id
        );
    $this->db->insert('page',$data);
}
```

Comment: can you specify reason ??

Answer (score 0):

Just do like this:

```
    $data = array(
        'title'=>$title,
        'description'=>$des
    );
    $this->db->insert('page',$data);
    $page_id = $this->db->insert_id();

    //To pass page_id to url column
    $this->db->where('page_id', $page_id);
    $data_1 = array('url'=>'page/view/'.$pageid);
    $this->db->update('page', $data_1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first get the highest Auto-Incremented id from select query and then, Use insert query for inserting the new row.
eg.

```
$id = $this->db->query("Select max(page_id) AS page_id from pages");
if($id->num_rows() > 0){
  $result = $id->result_array();
  $page_id = $result[0]['page_id'] +1;
}
// if table is empty
else{
  $page_id = 1;
} 
$data = array(
'title' => $title,
'description' => $des,
 'url'=>'page/view/'.$page_id );
$this->db->insert('page',$data);
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Please check it image for add auto increment id in phpmyadmin.